# Operators and addition of angular momenta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

Consider a two particle system with one particle having spin 1/2 and the other spin 1.

One state of the system is $||\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\rangle\rangle$ where a double ket means this is in the coupled basis. So $S=\frac{3}{2}\text{ and } m_s=\frac{3}{2}$. This state can also be written in the uncoupled basis as $|\frac{1}{2},1\rangle (\equiv~|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1\rangle )$.

If I want to act on this state with the $\hat{S^2}$ operator do I operate on the state represented in the coupled or uncoupled basis? Why and why not?

Comment: Do you have an expression for the coupled basis in terms of the uncoupled basis? And what does it look like?

Comment: It is in the post:

$||\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\rangle\rangle\equiv|\frac{1}{2},1\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter on which side $S^2$ acts. It should be equivalent shouldn't it?
here is the math.
$$\hat{S}=\hat{S_1}+\hat{S_2}$$
$$\implies \hat{S^2}=\hat{S_1^2}+\hat{S_2^2}+2\hat{S_1}.\hat{S_2}$$
$$S_1=S_x^1 \hat{i}+S_y^1 \hat{j}+S_z^1 \hat{k}$$
$$S_2=S_x^2 \hat{i}+S_y^2 \hat{j}+S_z^2 \hat{k}$$
$$\hat{S_1}.\hat{S_2}=S_x^1.S_x^2+S_y^1.S_y^2+S_z^1.S_z^2$$
Applying this on either side,
$$S^2||\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\rangle\rangle$$ $$=\hbar^2 (\frac{3}{2}. \frac{5}{2}) ||\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\rangle\rangle$$ $$=\hbar^2 \frac{15}{4} ||\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\rangle\rangle$$
Using the results above.
$$(\hat{S_1^2}+\hat{S_2^2}+2\hat{S_1}.\hat{S_2})|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1\rangle$$ $$=\frac{15}{4}\hbar^2|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1\rangle$$
Exactly the same!
Hope this helps!